# PostgreSQL does not return a XML with table data

Tags: xml, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using the latest ProgreSQL on a iMac.

When I use a simple SQL statement for returning a XML from a table but it doesn't return the data.

SQL:

```
select table_to_xml('company',true,false,'');
```

(I also tried '"company"')

Returns only xml:

```
company xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Comment: That works: https://rextester.com/TJSBB41444 maybe your SQL client doesn't display multi line values properly

Comment: You are right. I dump the output to a file and the records are visable. Strange that pgadmin not can handel the output of a query like this. Thanks a lot. Chris